# Update stacked bar chart with transition in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using the example listed here: http://bl.ocks.org/anotherjavadude/2940908 I've been feeling my way around D3 after some success with the basics.

I've built a stacked graph ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwmfjxay/3/)) and managed to get my initial transitions working, the problem arises when adding new data.

The error I'm receiving is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Here is the .data() where it falls down:

```
d3.select('rect.stacks')
    .data(function(d){return d;}) // error occurs here
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()-50)
    .transition()   
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })       
    .duration(1000);
```

For whatever reason when trying to update the 3D array being passed through has not been formatted correctly and I'm not sure why.

I've tried extracting chunks into functions to and exhausted my knowledge on things to try (which will explain any oddities / spaghetti).

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need a `d3.selectAll()` instead of `d3.select()`.

Comment: I did give that a go previously but it seems to throw the same error.

Comment: Well you need to use the same pattern as you do when initialising the graph -- https://jsfiddle.net/cwmfjxay/8/ There's something going on with the bars though that I can't figure out at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On update you are loosing the parent relationship between `g.valgroup` and `rect.stacks` because you are doing distinct selects.

You could try with this to keep the subselection and conserve data :

```
d3.selectAll("g.valgroup")
    .data(stacked)
.selectAll('rect.stacks')
    .data(function(d){return d;})  
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand()-50)
    .transition()   
    .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })       
    .duration(1000);
```

-> https://jsfiddle.net/y8ezx2fh/